# Flutter double notifications

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have chat app with end-to-end encryption made in Flutter. When push notifications arrive, the app process it, decrypt the content and show notification. But the problem is, that there is one more notification not created by the app with unencrypted content. It looks like this:

[image: double notifications]

This is really annoing and I don't know how to solve this problem.
Flutter logs:

```
Handling a background message: 0:1620226730325270%0454fd8a0454fd8a
W/FirebaseMessaging(23000): Notification Channel set in AndroidManifest.xml has not been created by the app. Default value will be used.
I/flutter (23000): true
D/FlutterSecureStoragePl(23000): Read: key exists => Running ensureInitStorageCipher
D/FlutterSecureStoragePl(23000): Initializing StorageCipher
D/FlutterSecureStoragePl(23000): StorageCipher initialization complete
D/NotificationSender(23000): Notification created
I/flutter (23000): Notification created
I/flutter (23000): Notification displayed
```

The log says that *Notification Channel set in AndroidManifest.xml has not been created by the app. Default value will be used.* But the channel was created by the app.
Thank you for you help.

Btw, I'm using AwesomeNitifications plugin for notifications.

**EDIT:**
*Notification Channel set in AndroidManifest.xml has not been created by the app. Default value will be used.* Error is not showing anymore, because I set notification channel id in FCM message this ID, but the notifications are still showing twice.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, Firebase push notifications can be sent in the background or exposed as soon as they arrive.

In this case, you will have to change the sending of push notifications, to be sent only in the background, and this way your filter will not expose the message that is encrypted.

For more info:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages